# How to handle the garbage character in oracle while export

Tags: oracle

I need help removing a garbage character while exporting to text file.
Data is coming like this...
On Copying to notepad:

```
   'ICL1485325                   �سيسات'
```

On exporting to file using sqlplus and character format export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 it is showing like square bracket.
dump of the column

Typ=96 Len=35: 73,67,76,49,52,56,53,51,50,53,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,63,211,234,211,199,202

I am trying regex_replace and translate, but they are making this column as null.

Comment: Could you use the replace function to target the question mark (CHR(63))? Something like: `select replace(field, CHR(63), '') from table;`

Comment: @runningviolent ...yes replace function works for me...